# How to insert the id of the user to the product in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm having problem with the Id of the user. I have 2 model, User and Product and there are a FK beetween them (1 User can have many Product). After logged, I want the user can add a new product, but the problem when i added a new product, the column User_ID is null, and i tried lots of way but i can't add the User_id to the Product.

This is my Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String productName;
    private double price;
    private String productType;
    private String description;
    private boolean sold = false;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;
```

This is my User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your email")
    @Email(message = "Enter a valid email address")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your password")
    @Length(min = 6, message = "Password must be at least 6 characters")
    private String password;
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your name")
    private String name;
    private boolean enable = true;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Product> products;
```

I tried to add like this but it doesn't work

```
@PostMapping("/mystore")
    public String addProduct(Product product) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        System.out.println(user.getId());
        product.setUser(user);
        productService.save(product);
        return "redirect:/mystore";
    }
```

So is there any way to get the ID of the user and add it into the product?

Comment: Can you try to delete `insertable = false ?` from @ManyToOne annotation in Product class

Comment: Why are you using eager loading here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are getting the user from authentication.getPrincipal(). you should get the user from the database and the Hinernate Session which is behind the Spring JPA will maintain into the session the User Entity. So, query the user form the DB using the principal, then set the user into product then save the product